# Sequence of the elements in JSON file is not correct

Tags: java, json

In order to create a `JSON` file including following content:

```
{"Person_0":{"name_0":["name of person_0"],"last name_0":["last name of person_0"],"phone_0":["phone of person_0"],"email_0":["email of person_0"],"address_0":["address of person_0"]}}
{"Person_1":{"name_1":["name of person_1"],"last name_1":["last name of person_1"],"phone_1":["phone of person_1"],"email_1":["email of person_1"],"address_1":["address of person_1"]}}
{"Person_2":{"name_2":["name of person_2"],"last name_2":["last name of person_2"],"phone_2":["phone of person_2"],"email_2":["email of person_2"],"address_2":["address of person_2"]}}
```

I have written following code in Java:

```
        JSONObject mainData;
        JSONObject subData;

        String[] mainDataString = new String[3];

        try {

            FileWriter jsonFile = new FileWriter("Json.json");

            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(jsonFile);
            writer.print("");

            for (int personIndex = 0; personIndex < 3; personIndex++) {
                mainData = new JSONObject();
                subData = new JSONObject();

                subData.append("name_" + personIndex, "name of person_" + personIndex);
                subData.append("last name_" + personIndex, "last name of person_" + personIndex);
                subData.append("phone_" + personIndex, "phone of person_" + personIndex);
                subData.append("email_" + personIndex, "email of person_" + personIndex);
                subData.append("address_" + personIndex, "address of person_" + personIndex);

                mainData.put("Person_" + personIndex, subData);

                mainDataString[personIndex] = mainData.toString();
                jsonFile.write(mainDataString[personIndex]);
                jsonFile.flush();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But, the output is as follows, where the sequence of the elements in `JSON` file is not as I want:

```
{"Person_0":{"email_0":["email of person_0"],"name_0":["name of person_0"],"address_0":["address of person_0"],"last name_0":["last name of person_0"],"phone_0":["phone of person_0"]}}
{"Person_1":{"phone_1":["phone of person_1"],"name_1":["name of person_1"],"email_1":["email of person_1"],"address_1":["address of person_1"],"last name_1":["last name of person_1"]}}
{"Person_2":{"phone_2":["phone of person_2"],"name_2":["name of person_2"],"email_2":["email of person_2"],"last name_2":["last name of person_2"],"address_2":["address of person_2"]}}
```

What is wrong in the code?

**P.S.** I tried both `subData.append` and `subData.put` .

Comment: If you mean order of properties in the object (name_*, last_name_* etc) then JSON doesn't have any notion of ordering of those. Think of it as a set of key-value pairs. Only elements in array [ ] are ordered.

Comment: From RFC 7159 -The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format: An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number, boolean, null, object, or array.

Comment: Why the order is so important?

Comment: @LHCHIN , Not important, just I thought there is something wrong in the code for getting the output where the order was messy ...

Comment: OK! I am just curious about that. So just as Krzysztof Cichocki answered, JSON libraries won't keep the order while serialization/deserialization. But there are still some ways to achieve this if you insist on doing that.

Answer (score 2):

**From RFC 7159 -The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format:** An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number, boolean, null, object, or array.

But if you insist, you may use LinkedHashMap and then serialise it, it would probably create an JSON with the proper order. Probably Gson library would work for this.